Golang gorm runtime error: invalid memory address appears after a long idle time when using same gorm.db connection
After some hours of running without problems I get the following runtime error:
[ERROR] runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 37 [running]:
runtime/debug.Stack()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:24 +0x5e
runtime/debug.PrintStack()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:16 +0x13
test/pkg.PanicHandler(0xc00889c000)
        /home/Desktop/testgo/pkg/error_handler.go:31 +0xbd
panic({0x2350120?, 0x45b0ba0?})
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:770 +0x132
github.com/projectdiscovery/fastdialer/fastdialer.(*Dialer).dial(0x0, {0x2fbd430?, 0x4700160?}, 0xc01e62a080)
        /home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/projectdiscovery/fastdialer@v0.1.6/fastdialer/dialer_private.go:66 +0x61
github.com/projectdiscovery/fastdialer/fastdialer.(*Dialer).Dial(0x0, {0x2fbd430, 0x4700160}, {0x2765f7a, 0x3}, {0xc0009f863c, 0x12})
        /home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/projectdiscovery/fastdialer@v0.1.6/fastdialer/dialer.go:198 +0xb9
github.com/projectdiscovery/v3/pkg/protocols/common/protocolstate.Init.func1({0x2fbd430?, 0x4700160?}, {0xc0009f863c?, 0x3?})
        /home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/projectdiscovery/v3@v3.3.0/pkg/protocols/common/protocolstate/state.go:150 +0x45
github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql.(*connector).Connect(0xc000d3e3f8, {0x2fbd430, 0x4700160})
        /home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql@v1.7.1/connector.go:46 +0x23c
database/sql.(*DB).conn(0xc000d4f790, {0x2fbd430, 0x4700160}, 0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1415 +0x71e
database/sql.(*DB).query(0xc000d4f790, {0x2fbd430, 0x4700160}, {0xc01949aa10, 0x47}, {0xc01e62a000, 0x2, 0x8}, 0x20?)
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1749 +0x57
database/sql.(*DB).QueryContext.func1(0xb8?)
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1732 +0x4f
database/sql.(*DB).retry(0x0?, 0xc000067378)
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1566 +0x42
database/sql.(*DB).QueryContext(0xc018128090?, {0x2fbd430?, 0x4700160?}, {0xc01949aa10?, 0x0?}, {0xc01e62a000?, 0x4113df?, 0x0?})
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1731 +0xc5
gorm.io/gorm/callbacks.Query(0xc018128090)
        /home/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.25.10/callbacks/query.go:19 +0xb2
gorm.io/gorm.(*processor).Execute(0xc000b7f4a0, 0xc00047e1e0?)
        /home/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.25.10/callbacks.go:130 +0x3cc
gorm.io/gorm.(*DB).First(0xc0122ae000?, {0x22f83e0, 0xc011a46030}, {0xc0203f8000, 0x2, 0x2})
        /home/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.25.10/finisher_api.go:129 +0x1b2
test/repository.ApiKeyRepositoryImpl.GetByKey({0xc018128030?}, {0xc0122ae000, 0x24})
        /home/Desktop/testgo/repository/api_key_repository.go:20 +0xc6
test/service.AuthServiceImpl.ValidateApiKey({{0x2fa52c0?, 0xc000b981f8?}}, 0x7ffffffffffffae6?)
        /home/Desktop/testgo/service/auth_service.go:28 +0x9f
test/router.Init.ValidateApiKeyWrapper.func3(0x2560360?)
        /home/Desktop/testgo/router/route.go:11 +0x26
github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(*Context).Next(...)
        /home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.10.0/context.go:185
github.com/gin-gonic/gin.CustomRecoveryWithWriter.func1(0xc00889c000)
        /home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.10.0/recovery.go:102 +0x7a
github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(*Context).Next(...)
        /home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.10.0/context.go:185
github.com/gin-gonic/gin.LoggerWithConfig.func1(0xc00889c000)
        /home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.10.0/logger.go:249 +0xe5
github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(*Context).Next(...)
        /home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.10.0/context.go:185
github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(*Engine).handleHTTPRequest(0xc000b9c000, 0xc00889c000)
        /home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.10.0/gin.go:633 +0x892
github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(*Engine).ServeHTTP(0xc000b9c000, {0x2fb7780, 0xc00085a7e0}, 0xc000af6120)
        /home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.10.0/gin.go:589 +0x1b2
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP({0xc0008a43c0?}, {0x2fb7780?, 0xc00085a7e0?}, 0x6?)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:3142 +0x8e
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc000b94120, {0x2fbd5f0, 0xc0008a42d0})
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2044 +0x5e8
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve in goroutine 1
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:3290 +0x4b4

I am using wire for dependency injection and this is how i make the connection (that is used by all repositories)
func ConnectToDB() *gorm.DB {
        var err error
        dsn := os.Getenv("DB_DSN")

        db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("Error connecting to database. Error: ", err)
        }
        sqlDB, _ := db.DB()
        sqlDB.SetMaxIdleConns(0)
        sqlDB.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Minute * 5)
        sqlDB.SetMaxOpenConns(5)
        return db
}

I can't figure why my app works fine for some time and then this happens for every subsequent connections
I could open and close the connection for every request but the official gorm documentation says that the connection can be safely used across different go routines

You are not using a single connection, but a connection pool1,2, represented by sql.DB. The you set the maximum number of idle connections to 0, so the pool will try to keep it at that value. As a result, as soon as a connection is deemed idling, it will be closed, closing every connection eventually.
Stop trying to micromanage the connection pool, use sqlDB.SetMaxIdleConns(1) to ensure at least one connection remains in the pool and use sqlDB.SetMaxOpenConns(x) for a value of x which is equal or higher to the number of concurrent requests that will be made to the database.
Calculating the proper value for SetMaxIdleConns is non-trivial. It is roughly the number of connection that can reliably be created during a given time interval subtracted from the number of concurrent requests happening during that time interval (in other words, the value used for SetMaxOpenConns) plus an additional safety buffer. I personally use the rule of thumb of using 1/3 of the maximum number of concurrent requests, but your mileage may vary by lightyears, especially when you have long running queries. You really need to monitor your application and find the proper values.

I tried to use your suggestion but it seems that the problem persists. As I said in the initial description, it works for some time, but after a certain period I get this error and no other connection can be established. I also printed the DB.Stats() and I get 100, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0s, 0, 0, 2. This means that I have 100 max conns, 3 open connections (of which all all in use )

@JohnMacStoian With the current information, this is impossible to debug. Try to create a [mre] using a simple go application and maybe docker compose.

try increasing Max Idle Connections number.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
